# Hiding IP address using CURL

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

**Similar**: [Possible to assign a new IP address on every http request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584272/possible-to-assign-a-new-ip-address-on-every-http-request)

---

Is it possible to display a different/spoofed IP address using CURL when you make requests to a server? If not, is there any alternative way of spoofing your IP address using PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Unless of course you use proxies and route your traffic through them.

Answer (score 2):

If you make a TCP/IP request, the other end needs to know your real address or you'll never receive a response back.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using TCP, then no - the TCP handshake is used at the beginning of each connection to ensure that both parties are who they say they are, so unless you're capable of intercepting network traffic between the server and the spoofed host, it's not possible.

See [TCP sequence prediction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Sequence_Prediction_Attack) for more information.